# How to loop on sorted (with custom sort) keys of a hash in Raku?

Tags: raku

Trying to progressively convert some Perl scripts to Raku. I am quite stuck with the following one, even after browsing quite a lot here and reading *Learning Perl 6* more deeply.

The part on which I can't make progress is the last loop (converted to `for`); getting keys and sorting them by month name and day number looks impossible, but I am sure it is doable.

Any hints on how to achieve this with "idiomatic" syntax would be really welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %totals;

while (<>) {
    if (/redis/ and /Partial/) {
        my($f1, $f2) = split(' ');
        my $w = $f1 . ' ' . $f2;
        $totals{$w}++;
    }
}

my %m = ("jan" => 1, "feb" => 2, "mar" => 3, "apr" => 4, "may" => 5, "jun" => 6,
         "jul" => 7, "aug" => 8, "sep" => 9, "oct" => 10, "nov" => 11, "dec" => 12);

foreach my $e (sort { my($a1, $a2) = split(' ', $a) ; my($b1, $b2) = split(' ', $b) ;
            $m{lc $a1} <=> $m{lc $b1} or $a2 <=> $b2 } keys %totals) {
    print "$e", " ", $totals{$e}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I haven't read beyond your question title yet because I check for comments/answers first and want to reply to your comment first. I've never heard of anyone not being able to edit their Qs. A quick google turned up [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/why-i-cant-edit-my-own-question). It only talks about account snafus. Then again it's generic to all stackexchange sites, not specifically stackoverflow, and individual stackexchange sites are allowed to have their own rules. Maybe search of meta.stackoverflow.com? I'll now turn my attention to your question. Oh, and Hi! :)

Comment: Oh, one other thing. The broader stackoverflow culture has historically been heavily biased toward dissuading friendly chit chat. While I feel we do need to be respectful of our hosts, Rakoons nevertheless generally (quietly, shhh) say "pfft" to such "we're all too busy to be human" stuff -- our historical norm is to encourage [`-Ofun`](https://raku.org/fun/), and part of that is encouraging things like friendliness and jokes. You have been warned...

Comment: Oh! You've posted your Perl code, not your Raku code. Fortunately I know a bit of Perl so fair enough, but... Oh! Now @wamba has posted an answer. Here's me too busy chatting... :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try something like:

```raku
enum Month (jan => 1, |<feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec>);

lines()
andthen .grep: /redis/&/Partial/
andthen .map: *.words
andthen .map: {Month::{.[0].lc} => .[1].Int}\ 
#or andthen .map: {Date.new: year => Date.today.year, month =>  Month::{.[0].lc},  day => .[1], }\
andthen  bag $_
andthen .sort
andthen .map: *.put;
```

Answer (score 10):

Fed with the same sample data, your perl code produces the same output as this.

```
my $data = q:to/END/; 
may 01 xxx3.1 Partial redis
may 01 xxx3.2 Partial redis
may 01 xxx3.3 Partial redis
apr 22 xxx2.2 Partial redis
apr 22 xxx2.1 Partial redis
mar 01 xxx1 redis Partial
some multi-line
string
END


sub sort-by( $value )
{
  state %m = <jan feb  mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec> Z=> 1..12;
  %m{ .[0].lc }, .[1] with $value.key.words;
}

say .key, ' ', .value.elems 
  for $data
    .lines
    .grep( /redis/ & /Partial/ )
    .classify( *.words[0..1].Str )
    .sort( &sort-by );
```

Answer (score 6):

I think that this is close to what you are asking for... also shows that perl6/raku is quite closely related to perl5 unless you want to get fancy...

```
#test data...
my %totals = %( 
    "jan 2" => 3,
    "jan 4" => 1,
    "feb 7" => 1,
);

my %m = %("jan" => 1, "feb" => 2, "mar" => 3, "apr" => 4, "may" => 5, "jun" => 6,
         "jul" => 7, "aug" => 8, "sep" => 9, "oct" => 10, "nov" => 11, "dec" => 12);

my &sorter = { 
    my ($a1, $a2) = split(' ', $^a); 
    my ($b1, $b2) = split(' ', $^b);
    %m{lc $a1} <=> %m{lc $b1} or $a2 <=> $b2 
}

for %totals.keys.sort(&sorter) ->$e {
    say "$e => {%totals{$e}}" 
}

#output
jan 2 => 3
jan 4 => 1
feb 7 => 1
```

The main changes are:

- %totals{$e} for $totals{$e}
- %() instead of {} for hash literals
- for with method syntax and -> instead of foreach with sub syntax
- $^a and $^b in sort routine need caret twigils (^)
- say is a bit cleaner than print

Comment: I recommend `put` for "bit cleaner than print". `put` is just as short and sweet as `say`, but is much simpler. It just means `print` with a newline. (Many PLs call this `printLn`, but that's verbose. So @Larry stole `puts` from Ruby and dropped the `s`. The `p` hints association with `print`. Fun mnemonic: **p**rint **u**nd **t**erminator.) Raku's `say` is unique. It uses `gist` which "humanizes" output. It's cool, but can be surprising/confusing for unsuspecting newbies. Especially folk who might confuse it with Perl's `say`, which is instead like Raku's `put`. In short, *first* think `put`.

Comment: Hmmm. Strictly speaking, you are correct. However, my preference is 'say'. (And 'dd' if I want to see  what's under the hood)

Comment: `say`, due to [`gist`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/gist), is either preferable or problematic, depending on what one knows, wants, and what's being `say`'d/`print`'d. Another option is [`.raku`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/raku). The `dd` routine is currently Rakudo compiler specific.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR** @wamba provides an idiomatic solution. This answer is a minimal "mechanical" translation instead.

I think your question and this answer suggests that a great way to learn many of Raku's basics as they relate to Perl is:

1. Feed a small Perl program into Rakudo;
2. Methodically investigate/fix each reported error until it works;
3. Post a question to StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Presuming that's what you did, great. If not, hopefully this answer will inspire you or other readers to try doing just that.

## The code

```
my %totals;

for lines() {
    if (/redis/ and /Partial/) {
        my ($f1, $f2) = split(' ', $_);
        my $w = $f1 ~ ' ' ~ $f2;
        %totals{$w}++;
    }
}

my %m = ("jan" => 1, "feb" => 2, "mar" => 3, "apr" => 4, "may" => 5, "jun" => 6,
         "jul" => 7, "aug" => 8, "sep" => 9, "oct" => 10, "nov" => 11, "dec" => 12);

for sort { my ($a1, $a2) = split(' ', $^a) ; my ($b1, $b2) = split(' ', $^b) ;
            %m{lc $a1} <=> %m{lc $b1} or $a2 <=> $b2 }, keys %totals
    -> $e {
    print "$e", " ", %totals{$e}, "\n";
}
```

works for the following test input:

```
feb 1 redis Partial
jan 2 Partial redis
jan 2 redis Partial
```

## The mechanical translation process

I began properly working on your question by feeding the code in your question to Rakudo. And was surprised to get `Unsupported use of <>. ...`. It was Perl code, not Rakunian!

Then I saw @wamba had provided an idiomatic solution. I decided I'd do the most direct translation possible instead. My first attempt worked. Order restored.

I pondered how best to explain my changes. I wondered what the error messages would be if I went back to the start and just fixed one at a time. The result was a delightful series of good error messages. So I've structured the rest of this answer as a series of error messages/fixes/discussions, each one leading to the next, until the program just works.

In the interests of simplicity I drop most of the info from the error messages. The messages/fixes are in the order I encountered them by fixing one at a time:

---

1. ```
   Unsupported use of <>.  In Raku please use: lines() to read input ...
   ------> while (<⏏>) {
   ```

   (`⏏` is Unicode's eject symbol, marking the point where the compiler conceptually "ejects" the code.)

   The idiomatic replacement of Perl's `while (<>)` is `for lines()`.

---

2. ```
   Variable '$f1' is not declared
   ------>         my(⏏$f1, $f2) ...
   ```

   Raku interprets code of the form `foo(...)` as a function call if it's where a function call makes sense. This takes priority over interpreting `foo` as a keyword (i.e. `my` as a variable declarator).

   Next, because `my($f1, $f2)` is interpreted as a function call, the `$f1` is interpreted as an argument that you haven't declared, leading to the error message.

   Inserting whitespace after the `my` fixes both the real problem and this apparent one.

   (This error occurred in multiple locations in your code; I applied the same fix each time.)

---

3. ```
   Unsupported use of .  to concatenate strings.  In Raku please use: ~.
   ------>         my $w = $f1 .⏏ ' ' . $f2;
   ```

   To help remember that `~` is used as a string operation in Raku, note that it looks like a piece of string.

---

4. ```
   Variable '$totals' is not declared.  Did you mean '%totals'?
   ------>         ⏏$totals{$w}++;
   ```

   - As Damian Conway notes, ["We took this Perl table of what do you use when, and we made it this table instead"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq2HkAYbG5o#t=9m30s).
   - The code `$totals{...}` is *syntactically* valid. One *can* bind or assign a hash (reference) to a scalar. But Rakudo (the Raku compiler) knows at compile time that the code hasn't declared a `$totals` variable, so it rightly complains.
   - Your code *has* declared a `%totals` variable, so Rakudo helpfully asks if you meant that.

   (This error occurred in multiple locations in your code; I applied the same fix each time.)

---

5. ```
   Unsupported use of 'foreach'.  In Raku please use: 'for'.
   ------> foreach⏏ my
   ```

   [Raku code tends to be shorter (and more readable) than Perl code](https://p6steve.wordpress.com/2020/04/17/raku-vs-perl-save-70/). It's mostly due to design that goes beyond mere paint, but little things like `s/for/foreach` don't hurt.

---

6. ```
   This appears to be Perl code
   ------> for ⏏my $e
   ```

   This error message is arguably [LTA](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#LTA) (I'm thinking "non-descriptive"). But it's equally arguably pretty good, all things considered.

   Perl and Raku support binding of a value to a new lexical variable/parameter scoped to a block. Perl uses `my`, and puts the variable(s) in front of the value(s). Raku puts the value(s) first, inserts a `->` between them and any variables, and skips the `my`.

   (There's a good deal of richness to this use of `->` that I'll not get into here because it doesn't matter for this example. But it's worth being aware that this change buys Rakoons a good deal, and you've got that to look forward to.)

---

7. ```
   Variable '$a' is not declared
   ------> for sort { my ($a1, $a2) = split(' ', ⏏$a)
   ```

   As Perl devs know, it has special variables `$a` and `$b`.

   Raku generalized this notion to [`$^foo` parameters](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#The_%5E_twigil), a convenient [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) way to add positional parameters to a closure while skipping the usual ceremony in which one has to specify the name twice (once to declare it, another time to use it).

   An unusual aspect of these that might initially seem crazy, but is actually very ergonomic, is that their formal parameter position is determined by their name. So, given `$^foo` and `$^bar`, the latter will bind to the *first* positional argument, `$^foo` to the second.

---

8. ```
   Missing comma after block argument to sort
   ------> { ... }⏏ keys
   ```

   I inserted a comma where indicated.

---

9. ```
   Calling split(Str) will never work with signature of the proto ($, $, |)
   ------>         my ($f1, $f2) = ⏏split(' '
   ```

   Some Perl routines implicitly presume use of `$_`. There's no *syntactic* way to know whether or not any given routine is implicitly using it. You just have to read each routine's definition. Raku dropped that.

   So Rakudo concludes the `split` routine is missing the string that's to be split.

   (The `|` in the "signature of the proto ($, $, |)" just means "other arguments that can *optionally* be passed", so you can ignore that. The `$, $` indicates *two* arguments are required, so we're missing one.)

   A quick check of the routine definition shows the `sub` version of `split` requires the string to be split as its *second* positional argument. Thus I switched to `split(' ', $_)`.

---

10. The code works. \o/

    Notably, **all** the actual error messages started with `===SORRY!=== Error while compiling`. That means they were all caught before the program even ran, which is nice.

Comment: The "process" part is indeed how I tried to proceed, but my inexperience stopped me before the end :) Thanks a lot for the very detailed explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the question. Write more! While you've got good answers and accepted @wamba's nice straightforward one, and while part of Raku's shine is due to 20 years of careful, loving, daily [bicarbonate baths](https://www.google.com/search?q=timtoady+bicarbonate), there will always be more than one way to think about things, and that spirit is alive and well in Raku culture and this SO. It's leading me to want to produce my own solution today, and, if it feels worth adding, posting a second answer from me. Welcome to the `[raku]` tag. 

Answer (score 3):

You've already got good answers, but I'm taking the opportunity to expose you to some other standard Raku tools and idioms that seemed natural to me for your problem.

For both my solutions:

- My equivalents of your `%totals` variable store keys in a structured data form rather than just as string keys. The supposed rationale is to simplify the sort and presentation. (But really it's to show you another way. It would of course be trivial to ensure the month and day numbers are concatenated as two two digit numbers to ensure correct sorting.) I use two different key types to show variations on this theme.
- I deal with conversion to/from month names by constructing hashes mapping names to numbers. I declare one with the `.pairs` or `.antipairs` method, and then apply the reverse to convert in the other direction. I do this one way in the first solution and the other in the second. And I set the number for `jan` to `0` in one solution and `1` in the other.

## Short and sweet, lean on `Pair`s

When declaring a `%foo` variable, if you don't specify its key type, it defaults to `Str`. But in this code, the key of each `Pair` in `%totals` is itself a `Pair`:

```
my %totals{Pair}; # Keys of the `Pair`s in `%totals` are themselves `Pair`s

my %months = <jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec> .pairs; # 0 => jan

for lines.grep(/redis/ & /Partial/)».words {
  ++%totals{ %months.antipairs.hash{ lc .[0] }.Int => .[1].Int }
}

for %totals .sort {
  printf "%3s %2d : %-d\n", %months{.key.key}, .key.value, .value
}
```

If no sort closure(s) are specified, Raku's `sort` routine, when applied to a hash, sorts its entries by comparing their keys using [`cmp`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/cmp). Furthermore, for an ordinary hash, comparing two keys means comparing two strings.

That would work fine for your situation if these strings were each date's month and day formatted as two digits each and then concatenated. Alternatively, splitting and schwartzian works fine too. Raku's really good at that stuff but I preferred to go a different way with this answer, so that the default sort did the right thing.

For this first solution, I picked `Pair`s as the key type. When `cmp` compares `Pair`s, it sorts first by key and then by value within that. Both key and value were coerced to `Int`s, thus the above code correctly sorts by month, then days within that.

## More structure, use `Date`s

This version adds structure and more fancy typing. It wraps the equivalent of the `%totals` hash (renamed `%.data`) into an outer object containing some utility routines, and makes the inner key object be a `Date` instead of a `Pair`:

```
role Totals {

  my %months = <jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec> .antipairs «+» 1; # jan => 1
  method month-name (Int $num --> Str)  { %months.antipairs.hash{$num} }
  method month-num  (Str $name --> Int) { %months{lc $name} }

  has %.data{Date} handles <sort>;

}

my $totals = Totals.new; 

for lines.grep(/redis/ & /Partial/)».words {
  ++$totals.data{ Date.new: :year(2000), :month(Totals.month-num: .[0]), :day(.[1]) }
}

for $totals .sort {
  printf "%3s %2d : %-d\n", Totals.month-name(.key.month), .key.day, .value
}
```

In the first solution, `sort` did the right thing because it was comparing `Pair`s, and `cmp` in turn did the right thing given how I'd set the pairs up.

In this solution `sort`/`cmp` do the right thing without needing to coerce string values to `Int`s, because the totals entries are `Date`s and they compare according to ordinary date comparison rules.

Comment: Many many thanks for your work and explanations, very clear and interesting to see new and typing-oriented approaches.
For now, with my test data, I get errors :/
```Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .raku, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.```
for the first one and
```Cannot call Date.new with these named parameters: day year month```
For the second one ; I have not been able to fix them after reading some Raku docs...

Comment: Ok, in my test data (real Redis logs), months have an initial capital and two spaces can separate month and day when day < 10 (so sorting on days is not OK with my own data). With your own test data (from your very first answer), the first one works, but the second one still gives ```Month out of range. Is: 0, should be in 1..12
  in block <unit> at f_full_6.raku line 16
```

Comment: Adjusting month-name and month-num with -1 / +1 works.
Still looking at adding 1 directly to .pairs instead :)

Comment: I ended up re-using the Z=> trick from another solution to construct the correct hash and now your 2 solutions work with my data.

Comment: Sorting issue was related to day not being Int, not to spaces.

Comment: First, thanks for expressing a positive view of things, and for working through all the problems. I *think* I've fixed all the problems you've raised in my latest edit. (To compare versions, click the link mentioning the latest edit directly below the answer.)

Comment: Second, sorry! Pretty bad when my own posted code doesn't handle my own test data! /o\ :) I know better but still occasionally make the N-years-a-rookie mistake of posting without a test of my final edit. Fortunately I almost never make that mistake, but of course you don't know that yet, and suffered the consequences.

Comment: I was torn about upvoting all your comments, because I've addressed them all, rendering them somewhat obsolete, and one of the effects of upvotes is to draw readers attention to them. But they were all the sorts of comments that are *ideal* -- friendly, correct, clear, pertinent, let readers (including me) know of problems with my answer, and led to me improving my answer. Comments don't get better than that! Please know that this suggests to me that you will not only find yourself very welcome here in the `[raku]` tag on SO, but will, I think, find yourself very welcome anywhere on SO.